# Automated OS Testing for Applications?

Tags: testing, operating-system, continuous-integration, cross-platform, integration

Is there any service like Travis-CI but for different OS's so that I can make sure a project builds - I'm specifically looking at those special build options that have to be configured for different OS's / setup's e.g. does a modification on setuptools work for multiple OS's?

Also anyway to check that a project works / has correct behavior on multiple OSs - something easier than running it in a large quantity of vm's ?

Thanks,
Eiy~

Answer (score 0):

Travis-CI currently supports Linux and OS X [[1](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/)].

There's a similar service for Windows, called Appveyor [[2](https://www.appveyor.com/)].